# Calling superclass method in superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, subclass, superclass

I am not able to find a good summary to describe my problem (suggestions welcome)

I have following two classes:

**Test1**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

abstract class Test1 {

    boolean condition = true;

    public void f() {
        System.out.println("Test1 : f");
    }

    public void g() {
        System.out.println("Test1 : g");
        f();
        if (condition) {
            f(); // call Test1.f() here. HOW?

            // Following didn't work
            try {
                Method m = Test1.class.getDeclaredMethod("f");
                m.invoke(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Test2**

```
class Test2 extends Test1 {

    public void f() {
        System.out.println("Test2 : f ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 t2 = new Test2();
        t2.g();
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Test1 : g
Test2 : f
Test2 : f
Test2 : f
```

The problem is that due to some special condition given by `condition` field in `Test1` I want to call `Test1`'s `f()` in `g()` even though I am calling using an object of `Test2`.

I tried reflection but it doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**
I didn't mention it specifically, but if you see carefully Test1 is abstract. So I cannot create its object.

Answer (score 3):

You should seriously consider the logic you are trying to build. The reason you tried to override the method f in child class has sure a reason behind it.

Alternatively, you can have boolean value as return from method f and in child method use `boolean r = super.f(); if(r){//execute child logic.}` This should solve your problem.

Comment: The logic is complex, that's true. But I don't see your point, `super.f()` returns `void`, that's not assignable to boolean.

Comment: I was recommending to change void to boolean. This will help take the decision on execution of child method logic.

Comment: The logic, whether to call the parent or not, comes from the internal logic of `g()`. It may not be implemented for all calls to `f()` (e.g from a call of `h()`).

Answer (score 1):

Add a method f2 in Test1:

```
private void f2() {
    System.out.println("Test1 : f");
}
public void f() {
    this.f2()
}
```

This way you can call f2() when the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

if the method name is same you can't do that. 
Other way is possible calling the super class methods directly in the sub class by using super.f().

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** specially for that person, who is not quite attentive, I'm giving the 
explanation.

In my code below I'm creating new **anonymous** class using brackets `{ }`. This allows me to make new instance of subclassed `Test1`.

---

Instead of using `reflection` you could do just such funny thing:

```
public void g() {
    System.out.println("Test1 : g");
    f();
    if (condition) {
         new Test1(){}.f();
    }
}
```

The only one disadvantage is that `f()` method called such way is invocation of method of absolutely another object.

Comment: Test1 is abstract, so I cannot create its object.

Comment: @Xolve, `new Test1(){}` it is an object created using anonymous class. So, I can.

Comment: @Xolve, may be you didn't noticed, but after `new Test1()` there are `{}` brackets.

Comment: @Andremoniy We don't know the reason why `Test1` is made abstract, there may be other methods that you have to implement.

Comment: @GaborSch we are talking about this particular case. BTW I +1 your answer, in common case your solution, of course, is better. My answer is just alternative to using reflection.

Comment: @Andremoniy Yes, in this particular case it is a nice tricky (but partial) solution. Still `f()` it is called on a different object.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance only allows you to inherit the behavior `super.f()`, override it `@Override`or both

```
@Override
public void f(){
    super.f(); 
    //do something  
}
```

You cant override a method and then try calling the parents method state before it was overridden. Inheritance doesn't work like that.